# MongoDB Query Document

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB Collection such as the Given Below

```
{
   "IslamabadICT": {
      "campus_name": "Islamabad",
      "campus_province": "ICT"
   },
   "KarachiSindh": {
      "campus_name": "Karachi",
      "campus_province": "Sindh"
   },
   "LahorePunjab": {
      "campus_name": "Lahore",
      "campus_province": "Punjab"
   },
   "PeshawarKPK": {
      "campus_name": "Peshawar",
      "campus_province": "KPK"
   }
}
```

and I want to Query all the documents where campus_name='Lahore'. I'm running the following command

db.campus.find({"campus_name":"Lahore"}).pretty() but it returns nothing. The version of MondoDB is 3.4 and I'm running mongo shell.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try this `db.campus.find({"LahorePunjab.campus_name":"Lahore"}).pretty()`

Comment: @Yogesh, that will not search for `campus_name` only, it'll first try to find the `LahorePunjab` field in document and If that fails it'll simply ignore the `campus_name` field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query that will return the document where `campus_name='Lahore'` -

```
db.campus.find().map( function(myDoc) { 
  for (var key in myDoc) {
    if(key != "_id" && myDoc[key].campus_name == "Lahore"){
      print( "Found it!!");
      return myDoc;
    }
  }
  return null;
} ).find(function(doc){if(doc!=null) return doc;});
```

**Apart from this**, I would highly recommend you to restructure your document format. One example could be to restructure the documents as follows -

```
{
    {
        "main": "IslamabadICT",
        "campus_name": "Islamabad",
        "campus_province": "ICT"
    },
    {
        "main": "KarachiSindh",
        "campus_name": "Karachi",
        "campus_province": "Sindh"
    },
    {
        "main": "LahorePunjab",
        "campus_name": "Lahore",
        "campus_province": "Punjab"
    },
    {
        "main": "PeshawarKPK",
        "campus_name": "Peshawar",
        "campus_province": "KPK"
    }
}
```

It will make the query a lot easier -

```
db.sht.find({campus_name:"Lahore"}).pretty()
```

Which is the one you tried in first place. :)

Comment: thanks.....I changed the format of my Collection, it's working well now